# Update Anorm dependency version in play project

Tags: playframework, dependencies, anorm

I am using play 2.3.1. The latest version of anorm updated to convert the sql array type column (multi value) to List[T].   I can not get the anorm.Column.columnToArray package in to my project. I have added the resolvers and dependency for anorm,  as "play" %% "anorm" % "2.10", but dependency for anorm is not getting updated. What is the correct form of adding the anorm as stand alone dependency. Please any one help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/anorm_2.11/
or
http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/play/anorm_2.11/

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
//  anorm,
  "com.typesafe.play" % "anorm_2.11" % "2.3.2",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.31"
)
```

I'm not sure that this version compatible with 2.3.1

Comment: It resolves the dependency, but the new features still not available

Comment: I found `anorm.Column.columnToArray` in `"com.typesafe.play" % "anorm_2.11" % "2.4-2014-08-02-fbea58a"` or `"com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4-2014-08-02-fbea58a"` but it seems a SNAPSHOT release.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.3.2" . It was merge by last June and 2.3.2 was released in July. Otherwise you may need to consider cleaning your ivy/m2 repository to be sure you don't have some obselete libraries on the way.